# WpForms - Adjusting the values before the form submits to database

Tags: php, wordpress

How to adjust the submitted Data before it gets submitted??
(I am trying to adjust the dropdown value's to use the value instead of the text)
Here is my code:

```
function wpf_dev_process( $fields, $entry, $form_data ) {
    if ( absint( $form_data['id'] ) !== 66203 ) {
        return $fields;
    }
        foreach ( $fields as $key => $value ){
            if ($fields[$key]["type"] == "select"){
                $fields[$key]["value"] =  $fields[$key]["value_raw"];
            }

        }
        echo "<pre>". print_r($fields, true)."</pre><hr>";
        return $fields;
}
add_action( 'wpforms_process', 'wpf_dev_process', 10, 3 );
```

My echo statement shows on my page the "corrected" data as can be seen here in this image [image]:

```
echo "<pre>". print_r($fields, true)."</pre><hr>";
```

But this is a User Registration Form and the data submitted to the Database is still the original value and not the value_raw that I change it to?

Anyone have any idea?

Comment: Could you explain in more detail? As I've understood you want to modify data before the process. What about the wpforms_process_before_form_data filter?

Comment: I have never hear of that filter.
I am using what WPForms support suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this using the `wpforms_user_registered` action.

After the system created the user, I used `update_user_meta` to insert the correct values from the drop-downs.